# How to fix HashMap updating every existing value instead of single value

Tags: java, hashmap

I've been working on a drunk walker coding problem (custom user classes, etc.), and I'm going insane trying to fix this small issue.

I messed around with the code (to no avail), and so with no hope in sight, I decided to get an outside opinion.

The code I used for adding into the hashmap is like this:

```
if (hashMap.containsKey(key) == false) {
    hashMap.put(key, 1);
}
else {
    hashMap.put(key, value + 1);
}
```

In theory, this should be completely fine. If the key is not saved in map, it is added to the map with a value of 1. If the key is actually there in the map, then the value is incremented by one. The key is just an instance of a custom class that takes two integer variables. It is being constantly updated.

At the end of the program, if I display entries in the hashmap with values greater than 1, it should look something like this:

```
Visited Intersection [avenue=8, street=42] 3 times!
Visited Intersection [avenue=8, street=63] 2 times!
```

But when I observed what the hashmap looked like with each function call, it looked like this:

```
Hash Map: {Intersection [avenue=6, street=22]=1}

Hash Map: {Intersection [avenue=6, street=23]=1, Intersection 
[avenue=6, street=23]=1}

Hash Map: {Intersection [avenue=6, street=22]=2, Intersection 
[avenue=6, street=22]=1}

Hash Map: {Intersection [avenue=5, street=22]=2, Intersection 
[avenue=5, street=22]=1, Intersection [avenue=5, street=22]=1}

Hash Map: {Intersection [avenue=6, street=22]=3, Intersection 
[avenue=6, street=22]=1, Intersection [avenue=6, street=22]=1}

...
```

Every entry in the hashmap was being overwritten, and the end product was this:

```
Visited Intersection [avenue=8, street=20] 3 times!
Visited Intersection [avenue=8, street=20] 2 times!
Visited Intersection [avenue=8, street=20] 2 times!
Visited Intersection [avenue=8, street=20] 2 times!
...
```

Originally I thought the code for adding into the hashmap was incorrect, since every key was being overwritten and only the last updated one is displayed, but now I think it has to do with the actual updating of the key.

Penny for your thoughts? Sorry if it's a bit vague.

Comment: `hashMap.put(key, value + 1);` <-- where is `value` being defined?

Comment: Yeah. Technically, value is just hashMap.get(key)

Comment: I dont understood your problem. What do you want and how look your key-class? And what is your value?

Comment: In addition to your actual bug: (1) Don't use `==` with booleans; use `!map.containsKey(key)`. (2) `map.merge(key, value, v -> v + 1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Every entry in the hashmap was being overwritten...

I suspect you don't quite understand how `HashMap` works.  `HashMap` stores a *reference* to the `key` not a copy.  I suspect that you are overwriting the fields in the `Intersection` after you have put it into the map.  This is a *very* bad pattern and can result in some very strange results.

Couple of things to check.

- You should be doing a `new Intersection(avenue, street)` each time.
- Consider making the 2 fields in your `Intersection` be `final`.  This is always a good pattern so you don't change the value of the key unintentionally.  For sure if one or both of the fields are "identity" field, it should be `final`.
- You need to make sure that the `Intersection` object has appropriate `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods that correctly identifies each value.  Otherwise each `Intersection` will be stored in the map regardless if they have the same `avenue` and `street` values.  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9739583/179850
- You should get getting the count of the intersections from the map and then incrementing the value.

Maybe something like:

```
Intersection key = new Intersection(8, 42);
...
Integer count = hashMap.get(key);
if (count == null) {
   hashMap.put(key, 1);
} else {
   hashMap.put(key, value + 1);
}
...
public class Intersection {
   // these fields can't be changed
   private final int avenue;
   private final int street;
   ...
```