# Java list of objects contained in another list of objects

Tags: java, list, object, contains

I have a bunch of users that I've put into a list, then I have another set of a bunch of users I've added to a separate list. I am trying to compare the first list of objects to the second list and create a new list of the unique objects.

```
        // List creation (new, old, unique)
        List<User> listNew = new ArrayList<User>();
        List<User> listOld = new ArrayList<User>();
        List<User> listUnique = new ArrayList<User>();

  ...

   for (User unique : listNew) {
        if (!listOld.contains(unique)) {
            listUnique.add(unique);
        }
    }
```

So I have this code to do that, but it just duplicates the listNew. How could I compare objects to one another? My class file is

```
public class User {

    private String fName;
    private String mInitial;
    private String lName;
    private String age;
    private String city;
    private String state;

....
```

Comment: Did you override the equals method in your User class?

Comment: Just use a `Set` type instead of a list. Sets cannot have duplicates to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers said, you need to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

You can use [Collection.removeAll](http://Collection.removeAll) method.

First you need to wrap the `listNew` into a HasSet which ensure the uniquness.

```
Collection<User> newUniques = new HashSet<User>();
newUniques.addAll(listNew);
newUniques.removeAll(listOld);
```

Now your `newUniques` will have desired results.

If you can use the apache commons, `ListUtils.removeAll(listNew, listOld)` is another option.

Comment: I _automatically generated_ `equals` and `hashCode` in my class and changed the unique list to a `Collection` but when I do the `removeAll` just like you suggested, it removes the entire list. Maybe I have a problem with the objects I created?

Comment: Did you add all the `listNew` elements to newly created collection

Comment: Yes, I did `newUniques.addAll(listNew);` and it populates it with about the same amount that's in listNew (20,010), I do a system.out to check the size of `newUniques` then I run `newUniques.removeAll(listOld);` and the size changes to 0.

Comment: `newUniques.removeAll(listOld);` will remove all the elements from `newUniques` which are there in `listOld`. If it is removing all the elements, then hope all `listNew` elements in `listOld` or there should be something wrong in hashCode or equals

Comment: In eclipse, I right clicked and through a few menus _auto-generated_ the hashCode and equals, so maybe that wasn't a good idea. Presently, I'm working to created my own, but don't really know what I'm doing, so I'm using this guide: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Comment: If you change any property after the object is added to set, it is no more give you the actual hashCode and all the methods dependent on hashCode like `contains` will fail. Hope you are not modifying the values.

Comment: Never got it working, but I don't think I should make a new post. My equals is `@Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if(o == null) return false;
  if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

     User other = (User) o;
     if(this.fName != other.fName) return false;
     if(! this.mInitial.equals(other.mInitial)) return false;
     if(! this.lName.equals(other.lName))   return false;
     if(! this.age.equals(other.age)) return false;
     if(! this.city.equals(other.city)) return false;
     if(! this.state.equals(other.state)) return false; 

     return true;
 }`

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `equals` and `hashCode` in the `User` class. If you don't have these methods implemented in `User`, `listOld.contains(unique)` will only return true if `listOld` contains exactly the same instance referenced by `unique`.

Check this out for the difference between identity and equality in java: [What is the difference between identity and equality in OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692863/what-is-the-difference-between-identity-and-equality-in-oop)

Comment: In addition, here is a relevant tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Comment: In Eclipse I auto generated `equals` and `hashCode` in the `User` class and my little loop still doesn't seem to detect that there are unique people in the _new_ users versus the _old_ users. Is auto generation a bad idea?

Comment: If you don't understand the code eclipse is generating, yes its a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sets have only unique elements by nature so that would be the correct type to use in your situation. First however you will need to properly override the *hashcode()* and *equals()* method of your *User* class. After that just try to add all instances to the a set and be done with it.

```
Set<User> uniqueUsers = new HashSet<User>();

for (User unique : listNew) {
    if (!listOld.contains(unique)) {
        uniqueUsers.add(unique);
    }
}
```