# Python "is not" method in Java

Tags: java, python, arrays, comparison

What is the java equivalent of pythons "is not"? I thought it was != but apparently they are different can anyone help?

```
if (array[j-i] is not 0):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `is not` for that in Python. `is` is for testing whether two names refer to the same object, not whether the objects are equal. The fact that it works here is coincidental and depends on the fact that  the standard Python implementation reuses small integers (so all references to `0` point to the same object). It won't work the way you want with other types, or even other integer values, and may not hold in other Python implementations. Use `!=` in Python, same as in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`if (array[j-i] != 0)` will get you what you're looking for. Sometimes you'll have to do `if (!array[j-i].equals("whatever"))`, and that may be what they were referring to. Please tell us what references you have for "but apparently they are different."

Answer (score 1):

The `is` keyword in Python checks for *identity*. The corresponding term in Java is `==`, hence `is not` corresponds to `!=`.

If you'd rather check for equality (check that the objects have the same value, but aren't necessarily the same object), you may use the `equals` method. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692863/what-is-the-difference-between-identity-and-equality-in-oop) for some good answers on the subject.