# Comparing An Entry In A Map With An Object

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a Map in Java like so,

```
private HashMap<String, Object[][]> theMap;
```

Where the key is a String and the entry is going to be something along the line of,

```
theMap = new HashMap<>();

Object[][] theData = {
    {Boolean.FALSE, "Text"}
};

theMap.put("Key1", theData);
```

Somewhere along the line I would like to check if an entry in the map is equivalent to another object. Currently I am doing it like this,

```
Object[][] tempData = {
    {Boolean.FALSE, "Text"}
};

for(Object key: entries.keySet()) {
    if(entries.get(key).equals(tempData)) {
        entries.remove(key);
    }
}
```

And it is not working.

I would prefer the comparison to be done with an object rather than with another map. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong with this comparison here?

Comment: Basically the problem here to compare two 2D arrays, you can use this :  Arrays.deepEquals(array1, array2);

Comment: And for the for loop use values instead of keys.(for(Object value:entries.values()) Makes the code cleaner

Comment: By the way since you are removing entries as you go maybe you should use an Iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not getting equality is that arrays inherit `Object#equals()` which is based on identity, not equality of contents.  You could consider using `java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(Object[], Object[])` to compare.

That is the answer to the immediate question.  However, using a 2-dimensional array of `Object` to hold a `boolean` and a `String` is really bad code smell and indicates you need to encapsulate what you are putting in the array.

Comment: This did solve my problem, thank you. And what would your suggestion be to change how I'm holding onto my data other than an object?

Comment: Yes absolutely.  But that will require understanding what you're trying to store in the map to design an appropriate class.  Give it a shot yourself and don't forget to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` appropriately.  If you end up having problems doing that post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

**Identity vs Equivalence**

Please make sure that you understand that by default the `equals()` method of `Object` checks on whether two object references are referring to the same object (**identity**), which is not what your code is checking.

Instead, your code is checking whether the two objects (the values you put on the map) are having the same value (**equivalence**).

Here are two articles about this topic:

1. [What is the difference between identity and equality in OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692863/what-is-the-difference-between-identity-and-equality-in-oop)
2. [Overriding equals method in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/)

In this particular problem of yours, I think the solution involves two steps:

1. Your `tempData` and `theData` does not seems to be an array
   of elements of the same type (it does not appear to be a 2-dimensional
   array either).  Instead, it contains a `Boolean` value and then a 
   `String` value.  In this case, I think you really should think
   through what this thingy is and design a class for it (I am showing
   an example below)
2. The class should override the `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) methods
   so that you can use its `equals()` for equivalence checking.

Note also that your IDE (e.g. `Eclipse`) probably can generate a template for `equals()` and `hashCode()` for you.

Example: (here I assume your `Boolean` represents a condition, and your `String` represents a message)

```
class MyRecord {
    private Boolean condition;
    private String  message;
    public Boolean getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }
    public void setCondition(Boolean condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((condition == null) ? 0 : condition.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((message == null) ? 0 : message.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyRecord other = (MyRecord) obj;
        if (condition == null) {
            if (other.condition != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!condition.equals(other.condition))
            return false;
        if (message == null) {
            if (other.message != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!message.equals(other.message))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```