# Change two variables at the same time

Tags: java

Can you link two or more variables so that if you change the value of one the rest change to the same value as well?

I thought of making a method that does that but I wanna know if there is an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Seems like you just want to make those variables point to the same object

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: Yeah I saw something called pointers in c++ and thought that you could point to of them to each other and if you changed one the other one would follow

Comment: You'll want to look at how java handles identity and equality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692863/what-is-the-difference-between-identity-and-equality-in-oop#1692882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
JFrame a = new JFrame("A");

JFrame b = new JFrame("B");

a = b = new JFrame("C");

System.out.println(a.getTitle() + " - " + b.getTitle());

a.setTitle("D");

System.out.println(a.getTitle() + " - " + b.getTitle());
```

You assign same instance to multiple variables and after that change only one.

I used JFrame just as example.

P.S.: This works only for objects. For primitives(`byte, short, int, long, float, double, boolean, char and String`) doesn't. If you want to work with primitives, you need to create an Class which has that primitives as fields and change them via object.

Comment: So it has to be the same object and it can't be one array and one simple object

Comment: @AlexTanasa Exactly. If you want for different objects you need to create an special method for your case.