# Instance equality check returning false?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, equality

I have created a simple Vector class in JavaScript with a constructor and some methods. The add method returns a new Vector instance. When comparing the return value of the add method with a new instance declared with the same values `false` is returned. I have also tried changing the equality operator to a double equals so I believe the issue is not to do with references.

```js
class Vector {
  constructor(components) {
    this.length = components.length;
    this.contents = components;
  }

  add(vector) {
    if (this.length === vector.length) {
      let a = [];
      this.contents.forEach((cur, index) =>
        a.push(cur + vector.contents[index])
      );
      return new Vector(a);
    }
    throw Error;
  }

  subtract(vector) {
    if (this.length === vector.length) {
      let a = [];
      this.contents.forEach((cur, index) =>
        a.push(cur - vector.contents[index])
      );
      return new Vector(a);
    }
    throw Error;
  }

  dot(vector) {
    return this.contents.reduce(
      (acc, cur, index) => (acc += cur * vector.contents[index]),
      0
    );
  }

  norm() {
    return this.contents.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc += Math.pow(cur, 2)), 0);
  }

  equals(vector) {
    return this.contents === vector;
  }
  toString() {
    return this.contents.toString();
  }
}

let a = new Vector([10, 20, 30]);
let b = new Vector([5, 15, 25]);

console.log(new Vector([15, 35, 55]));
console.log(a.add(b));

//Why does the log below return false?
console.log(new Vector([15, 35, 55]) === a.add(b));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not compare two distinct objects with `==` nor with `===`, if you want to test on object equality (see also [MDN Web Docs Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)).

In the case of objects these both operators only return `true`, if the same object is referenced.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects%20on%20how%20to) on how to test for object equality, because that seems to be what you want to achieve.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692863/what-is-the-difference-between-identity-and-equality-in-oop) for the difference between object equality and object identity.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing arrays using `===`  you are comparing their addresses. Check it out:

```
> a = [1,2]
[ 1, 2 ]
> b = [1,2]
[ 1, 2 ]
> a === b
false
```

If you want the check if the arrays contain the same elements, you could iterate over all elements and compare them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript).

By the way, you should also write `throw **new** Error()` (without the asterisks).